# Using "Class" keyword for Plug/Unplug modules of an Actionscript project

Tags: actionscript-3

I always wonder, what is the best way in AS3.0 to make plugins that are insertable and removable as required. Something similar to how, windows update take place on local computers via internet from their servers. Or say, how different commands and effects can be loaded and unloaded in a photoshop program.

What is see is that Actionscript provides two ( or may be more, out of my knowledge ) ways to do that. One is having an external swf file ( So that they may be loaded at runtime, and classes can be used). Another way is using "Class" keyword.

**My question starts here.**

1) Is it a good practice to use "Class" keyword to load new classes dynamically, to make a module pluggable/unpluggable.

2) Is it good to use it extensively in the whole project. Such that say 90% of classes use Class keyword to get loaded. And thus making the whole of the project updatable at runtime also?  What may be the problems i may face usint it extensively ( like Memory leakage ??, High CPU usage ?? )

Comment: I think you might be leaning towards something like SpringAS though I'm not sure how mature the project has become the idea is inversion of control where you can define interfaces for all your key components in the application and then write different implementations and swap them out using a configuration file that loads things at runtime, in terms of details on how this is implemented I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you considering this for a web-served Flash / Flex project or for an AIR app?

Comment: Well, as AS3 is common to both so it can be used for both, i think.